# Why select value doesnt get updated by async pipe using [value] in Angular?

Tags: angular

Using `[value]` doesnt change the value of the select element when a new Value of the `$currentValue` Observable emits. Using `[ngModel]="currentValue.value?.id"` the code works as intended.
Why is this the case ? The `{{currentValue.value | json }}` also get updatet when a new value emits.

`select.compontent.html`

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{value: $currentValues | async} as currentValues">
  <ng-container *ngIf="{value: $currentValue | async} as currentValue">
    {{currentValue.value | json }} <br> 
    <select [value]="currentValue.value?.id" (change)="onZyklusChange($event)"> 
      <option *ngFor="let zyklus of currentValues.value" [value]="zyklus.id">
        {{zyklus.id}} {{zyklus.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

`select.component.ts`

```
$currentValues: Observable<IZyklus[]>;
  $currentValue: Observable<IZyklus>;
  constructor(private service: ZyklusService) {
    this.$currentValues = service.getAccessibleZyklen();
    this.$currentValue = service.getCurrentElement();
  }
```

And the following Interface `IZyklus`

```
export interface IZyklus {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  userLoggedIn: boolean
}
```

Thanks in advance!

I tried using manual subscribing and setting the value by hand. Logging the new values of the Observable to check if a new value emits

Comment: Why aren't you using `[(ngModel)]`?

Comment: Thought you only doing one way binding with async pipe

Comment: Okay, but I think (my experience is) that the [`SelectValueAccessor`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/forms/src/directives/select_control_value_accessor.ts) does a lot different than setting the value. I would just give it a try `<select [ngModel]="currentValue.value?.id" (ngModelChange)="onZyklusChange($event)">`

Comment: And use [`ngValue`](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#using-select-controls-in-a-template-driven-form) instead

Comment: As I mentioned in the problem description I use the ngModel and i know it works, but i want to know whats the difference between those two concepts in this scenario. Because the `{{currentValue.value | json }}` gets updated when a new value emits but not the `[value]` (but the `[ngModel]` does). @Pieterjan